# Is it a bad idea to put application code in virtual environment directory?

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, python-venv

I'm working on a project with someone who followed a tutorial to setup a Django appplication using a `venv` environment. Everything is well done, but the tutorial suggested putting his application code **inside** the `venv` directory. In other words, he did something like this:

```
pyvenv myenv
cd myenv
mkdir webapp
cd webapp
(...put in app code and run it...)
```

Is this a bad idea? Are there any negative consequences?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. The whole point of virtual envs is to do that.

Comment: @freakish: usually you put environment in project directory, not the other way around

Comment: @GingerPlusPlus How is that different?

Comment: @freakish env in project vs project in env

Comment: @GingerPlusPlus I don't understand the concept of "env in project". You create a separate venv folder inside your project?

Comment: @freakish venv is separate folder. Some people put it in project directory and add it to .gitignore, some put it in completely different place (`virtualenvwrapper`), haven't heard of anyone who would put by hand anything into the venv dir. Myself, I never worked on project big enough to bother with venv.

Comment: @GingerPlusPlus Right, well I've never seen people adding venvs to project folders. On the other hand I haven't seen people putting projects in venvs as well. These two separated makes the most sense (virtualenvwrapper ftw). However they do end up in venv anyway because of the installation process.

Answer (score 1):

It is a bad idea. It is very common to delete and re-create isolated python environments (which have the unfortunate common name "virtual environments", although nothing's virtual about them) when something isn't working properly. It is also quite common to have two such environments for a single project—one for Python 2 and one for Python 3. You might also have one for Django 1.8, one for Django 1.9, and one for Django 1.10.

The practice of putting your project inside the isolated environment might work for a while, but no doubt it will create confusion and problems later.

Answer (score 0):

This is verging on opinion, but it doesn't look like a bad idea. It may be better to have the project and env separate for organizational purposes.

How good or bad or bad of an idea putting the code in a virtual env is will depend on context. During a fully automated deployment its probably ok. During development its probably a bad idea.